# Set of edges is MST?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Given a Graph $G = (V,E)$ and given a subset $ T \subset E$.
I would like to test, whether T is already a MST of G or not in constant time.

Note: If $T^{MST}$ is the MST of G, then we know that $T \subset T^{MST}.$

I can think of approaches in linear time, but I cannot come up with anything in linear time.

Is there maybe a way to figure out beforehand, how many edges are contained in the MST of G?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a way you can just check if each vertex is touching something in $T$?

Comment: I could check this, but wouldn't this result in linear time in the number of vertices?

Comment: With regard to the last question, the number of edges in a spanning tree of $G$ is one less than the number of vertices of $G$.

Comment: Ok, that's great! Then I could basically test, $|T| = n-1$.

Comment: That wouldn't necessarily tell you its a spanning tree though.

Comment: So, one condition is $|T|=n-1$ (where $n=|V|$), and the other condition is that all the vertices are covered by $T$.

Comment: But you're looking for a *minimal* spanning tree, right? In a weighted graph? Not every spanning tree has minimal weight.

Comment: I just realized that I left out an important information. If $T^{MST}$ is the MST of G, then $T \subset T^{MST}$ and in each iteration I need to test whether $T$ is already $T^{MST}$. I'll add this information to the post. @GerryMyerson: The statement you made in the comments about the cardinality of the MST of a Graph. If you write this as an answer below, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of edges in a spanning tree of a graph $G$ is one less than the number of vertices of $G$.